# Can "de nada" be used sarcastically?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

In English (or at least in the U.S.), we say "You're *welcome.*" in a sarcastic tone when someone responds in an ungrateful or greedy way to something we've done for them, or when we think we deserve more gratitude (in my experience, this is usually for small favors).

For example, a sarcastic "you're welcome" could be used if I hand something to someone else (like a tool) so that they don't have to get up, and they snatch it out of my hand without saying thanks.

**Can "de nada" be used sarcastically, or do Spanish speakers use something else?** If you want to get region-specific, I'm most curious about Mexico and Spain.

Comment: Of course, yes. It is used very much like this.

Comment: @fedorqui Wow, that was fast. I still have a lot to learn about Spanish, I see... The native speakers I interact with the most are not sarcastic (or passive-aggressive), so I don't really have the chance to hear any Spanish sarcasm.

Comment: A lot of stuff that you expect are like English language specific are sometimes not. It's kinda weird and is not universal. Like venir for example has the same slang meaning as come does in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanto "Gracias" como "De nada", son parte de una misma expresión usada como respuesta cortés cuando alguien realiza un hecho grato. Una vez realizada ó cerrado el "Gracias - De nada", la charla se acaba ó se pasa a otro punto de la conversación.

En Español se puede utilizar tanto la ironía como el sarcasmo, tanto dentro de la expresión "Gracias" como en la expresión "De nada". Suele aparecer cuando se atiende al sentido de burla o cuando se da a entender algo distinto o contrario de lo que se dice.

Esta expresión, "Gracias" - "De nada", no siempre funciona de la misma forma o de la manera deseada y serán los lugares, las particularidades, las costumbres y conductas entre conocidos, lo que nos da una noción de lo que de fuera se pueda percibir, a eso se añaden otras formas que han ido sustituyendo al clásico "De nada" como son; ¡no hay de qué!, ¡No te preocupes!, ¡nada, nada!, ¡Esta bien!, ¡OK!, ¡Sin problemas!, ¡bien!,¡ esta bien!,¡un placer!..... y que en incontables ocasiones se pueden escuchar tras un ¡Gracias! expresado por alguien.

Igualmente, en ocasiones, ejem. un camarero después de solicitarle una marca de cerveza, se va, al poco viene con ella y al ponerla nos dice directamente "gracias" y nosotros respondemos simplemente con otro "gracias", no con un "De nada".

Cuando la situación que se ha dado, resulta provocada por una persona desagradecida o que ha causado la molestia y no se da cuenta de su comportamiento o lo ocasionado, solo si ellos "Dan las Gracias", el que dice el "De nada", puede utilizar un tono negativo ó suspirar en ese momento, si tiene que entregar dinero, lo hace de mal gana...donde denota y haciendo saber el comportamiento grosero. Otros, si dan las gracias, no contestan y simplemente ignoran.

Es Español y según las zonas la confianza juega con las palabras, así la expresión "Gracias" puede conducir a la palabra "Gracioso ó Graciosillo" y "De nada" a nada ó la versión corta na'.

Ejemplos locales;

- Así cuando alguien da las "Gracias", como parte del final de la conversación, ejem. en una reunión, el otro en lugar de decir "De nada", dice; si, si...no te hagas el "Graciosillo", es decir no digas Gracias todavía) e invítanos a unos chupitos.
- A veces la cuestión es a la inversa, eran unos amigos que siempre andaban juntos, uno de ellos se pone enfermo, pero en semanas no recibe ni la visita ni la llamada de su amigo. Solo cuando sale a la calle y lo ve, después del mes, el hombre que ha estado enfermo le dice al amigo..."Gracias, eh muchas Gracias", como diciendo, anda que has venido a visitarme. Entonces el otro hombre contesta, "De nada hombre, de nada", "No hay de que", a la próxima repetimos.
- En otras ocasiones alguien puede visitar tu casa y sin mediar palabra, se pone a buscar entre tus cosas, sacar tus libros ante tu presencia, ponerlos en otro sitio.. hasta que llega un momento en que dices "De nada eh", (como diciendo, podrías preguntar o cortarte un poco).
- Un hombre entre los vecinos nunca tenía monedas pequeñas en efectivo y cuando llegaba a la maquina del parking para aparcar su coche, pedía continuamente a los allí presentes cambio, sin embargo, cuando le hacías el favor de cambiar el dinero, el hombre sin decir nada, se iba y nunca daba las gracias, algunos le decían gracias eh, otros, "gracias por nada", otros "de nada" y otros directamente le llamaban la atención sabe que es ó se dice "De nada" ¿no?.
- Algunas situaciones son graciosas, alguien hace un trabajo, pero el otro no ha quedado muy contento con lo que recibe, así cuando se despiden uno da las gracias por la gran labor realizada y el que se encuentra un poco molesto dice.. "Otro día te contesto". (Como diciendo en otro momento te digo "De nada", porque ahora no es un buen momento, me esperaba que mi trabajo fuera algo más valorado)

En Español como en otros idiomas imagino que habrá decenas o cientos de anécdotas, en cualquier caso, cuando el comportamiento de alguien puede ser considerado como grosero, no útil o que se nos ignora, utilizamos expresiones y tonos según los casos, con el mismo "Gracias", "De nada" ó por el estilo, irónicas, sarcásticas ó de burlar, con los que intentamos no enfadarnos y hacer ver a la otra persona su fallo. A veces, ni por esas es posible.

Comment: ¡Gracias por las explicaciones y los ejemplos detallados! Esta es una respuesta muy buena.

Answer (score 2):

In spanish language, the expression "De nada" can be used ---and in fact, it is used--- in an ironic sense, although the usual thing is to do it orally, and less so in writing.

The normal thing is to also accompany it with a specific gesture (non-verbal communication), which intensifies the ironic or sarcastic tone.